# Regex range between 0 and 100 including two decimal

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out a regex expression that does the following. Both conditions below must be true:
1) Between 0 and 100 inclusive
2) Can contain one or two decimals only but not obligatory.

It should not allow 100.01 or 100.1
100 is the maximum value, or 100.0 or 100.00

I tried `^(100(?:\.00)?|0(?:\.\d\d)?|\d?\d(?:\.\d\d)?)$`
which helped me in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252506/float-regex-format-for-a-2-decimal-place-number-between-0-and-100)
but this does not accept `99.0` (one decimal).
I'm probably very close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make each second decimal digit optional:

```
^(?:100(?:\.00?)?|\d?\d(?:\.\d\d?)?)$
              ^                 ^
```

See the [updated regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hW9kP5/2). The `0(?:\.\d\d)?` alternative is covered by `\d?\d(?:\.\d\d)?` one (as per [Sebastian's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416212/regex-range-between-0-and-100-including-two-decimal/37416267?noredirect=1#comment62338796_37416267))  and can thus be removed.

The `?` quantifier matches one or zero occurrences of the subpattern it quantifies.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of an alternation group:

  - `100(?:\.00?)?` - `100`, `100.0` or `100.00` (the `.00` is optional and the last `0` is optional, too)
  - `\d?\d(?:\.\d\d?)?` - an optional digit followed by an obligatory digit followed with an optional sequence of a dot, a digit and *an optional digit*.
- `)` - end of the alternation group
- `$` - end of string.

**BONUS**: If the number can have *either* `.` (dot) or `,` (comma) as a decimal separator, you can replace **all** `\.` patterns in the regex with `[.,]`:

```js
^(?:100(?:[.,]00?)?|\d?\d(?:[.,]\d\d?)?)$
```

Comment: `0(?:\.\d\d?)?` is already covered by `\d?\d(?:\.\d\d?)?` - so why not remove it?

Comment: @SebastianProske: I just focused on the main point - making the 2nd decimal optional. Yes, true, it is covered.