# Regex range including negative decimal numbers between -100 and 100 including but not requiring 2 decimal points

Tags: regex, forms, validation

I need some help coming up with a Regex that allows a decimal value between -100 and 100.
It can have up to two decimal places but decimals should not be required.

I have this for 0 - 100 based on this question:
[Regex range between 0 and 100 including two decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416212/regex-range-between-0-and-100-including-two-decimal)

```
^(?:100(?:\.00?)?|\d?\d(?:\.\d\d?)?)$
```

Comment: Why can't you just add `-?` after the `^`?

Comment: This was the answer thank you. ^-?(?:100(?:\.00?)?|\d?\d(?:\.\d\d?)?)$

Answer (score 0):

You can try this expression :

```
/^-?(?:100|[0-9]{1,2})(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/gm
```

- `^` asserts position at start of a line
- `-?` matches the character `-` literally (case sensitive)

  - `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) (*negatives are optional*)
- Non-capturing group `(?:100|[0-9]{1,2})` (*hundred or less than*)

  - 1st Alternative `100` matches the characters `100` literally (case sensitive)
  - 2nd Alternative `[0-9]{1,2}` matches a single character present in the list `[0-9]`
  - `{1,2}` Quantifier — Matches between 1 and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9 (case sensitive)
- Non-capturing group `(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?` (*decimals not required*)

  - `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `\.` matches the character `.` literally (case sensitive)
  - `[0-9]{1,2}` matches a single character present in the list `[0-9]`
  - `{1,2}` Quantifier — Matches between 1 and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9 (case sensitive)
- `$` asserts position at the end of a line

Global pattern modifier/flags :

- `g` : global. All matches (don't return after first match)
- `m` : multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)